# Calling stored procedure from stored procedure intermittently fails

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a report that calls a stored procedure which in turn calls a stored procedure.

The parent sp is one that aggregates expenses vs revenue over a multi-year contract.

The child sp returns raw data for a single budget year.

This works beautifully most of the time. However, sometimes we get an error thrown that the first field in the child sp cannot be found. This field comes from a simple select statement.

The problem appears to occur at times of the day when there is a heavier load on the server.

Here is the portion of the parent sp where the child sp is called:

```
declare c_by cursor for (select ccbyId from #budgetYears)
open c_by
fetch next from c_by into @c_byId
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
Begin

begin try

    insert into #fullDataSet 
    EXEC [dbo].[rptByToDate]
        @ClientContractBudgetYear   = @c_byId 
        ,@userID                    = @userID 
        ,@DBName                    = @DBName 


end try
begin catch

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK

    DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), @ErrSeverity int
    SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
         @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()

    RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)

end catch

fetch next from c_by into @c_byId
End
close c_by
deallocate c_by
```

What am i missing?